# How to RBind First 4 Column one above Other with Tag

Tags: r

Below i have to tried to reproduce in representable Form

```
 `v<- data.frame(C1TEMP = c(3,6,1,8,9,2,2,9,1,23),
               C1VIB = c(5,6,1,8,9,2,2,9,1,23),
               C1DE = c(9,6,1,8,9,2,2,9,1,23),
               C1NDE = c(8,6,1,8,9,2,2,9,1,23),

               C2TEMP = c(5,6,1,8,9,2,2,9,1,23),
               C2VIB = c(378,6,1,8,9,2,2,9,1,23),
               C2DE = c(3,78,1,8,9,2,2,9,1,23),
               C2NDE = c(3,6,1,8,9,2,2,9,1,23),

               C3TEMP= c(3,6,89,8,9,2,2,9,1,23),
               C3VIB = c(3,6,1,98,9,2,2,9,1,23),
               C3DE = c(33,56,91,82,99,12,22,19,81,23),
               C3NDE = c(13,76,91,88,59,42,22,39,21,23))`
```

Here i want to rbind Every 4 column one above each Other with the tag No Along. And No of Columns will always be divisible of 4. I here with also Attaching an image for a clear picture what result should be expected.

EXPECTED OUTPUT:
[image]

Comment: I am not sure rbind is the correct solution, as binding by position is not well advised. You may try stg like melt to have one column variable and one column number, modifying the variable name then using dcast to reshape it in the correct format. That way you don't use position and your code is more reliable.

Comment: @bc004346 @YCR @KoenV Just a Thought to make code more adaptable to Any Number of Column RBinding,Let say `if i want to Rbind by N no of Column & N can be any number from 1 to 10`.So can we have Efficient code for that.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with YCR's comment. Still, this is a way to tackle your problem. Use the following code:

```
# data frames need column headers, so convert to matrix
v01 <- as.matrix(v[, 1:4])
v02 <- as.matrix(v[, 5:8])
v03 <- as.matrix(v[, 9:12])

# remove columnnames
colnames(v01) <- NULL
colnames(v02) <- NULL
colnames(v03) <- NULL

# now you can use rbind and give the columnnames back
v2 <- rbind( v01, v02, v03)
colnames(v2) <- c("C1TEMP", "C1VIB", "C1DE", "C1NDE")
v2
```

Comment: I appreciate your solution sir , this code will be used in shiny application where the user will upload some .csv file and `number of column is not fix` it is not mandotory that `No of Column wiill be 4 only` it can be random But divisible by 5 or 4 or 8.

Comment: My pleasure. Feel free to mark this code as working, or to mark as "chosen solution".

Answer (score 0):

try this
It is a bit more convoluted than previous answers but it should be more adaptable to other data frames

```
# how many blocks have you got?
  howMany <-table(gsub(names(v),pattern = "[0-9]",replacement = ""))[1] 
# make a common name string
  NAMES <- unique(gsub(names(v),pattern = "[0-9]",replacement = ""))

# create a list
  list() -> V
  for(i in 1:howMany){
  # get the column with matching index number
    v[,grep(names(v),pattern = i)] -> vi
    names(vi) <- NAMES# change name
    data.frame(Tag=i,vi) -> V[[i]]# put it in the list
}
# combine tables in the list into one list
  do.call(rbind,V)
```

Nils

Comment: I appreciate your solution This code will only work when column name will contain number , In case of letters it won't.

Answer (score 0):

The melt and reshape way:

It implies to get an identifier per row:

```
v<- data.frame(C1TEMP = c(3,6,1,8,9,2,2,9,1,23),
           C1VIB = c(5,6,1,8,9,2,2,9,1,23),
           C1DE = c(9,6,1,8,9,2,2,9,1,23),
           C1NDE = c(8,6,1,8,9,2,2,9,1,23),

           C2TEMP = c(5,6,1,8,9,2,2,9,1,23),
           C2VIB = c(378,6,1,8,9,2,2,9,1,23),
           C2DE = c(3,78,1,8,9,2,2,9,1,23),
           C2NDE = c(3,6,1,8,9,2,2,9,1,23),

           C3TEMP= c(3,6,89,8,9,2,2,9,1,23),
           C3VIB = c(3,6,1,98,9,2,2,9,1,23),
           C3DE = c(33,56,91,82,99,12,22,19,81,23),
           C3NDE = c(13,76,91,88,59,42,22,39,21,23),

           id = 1:10
           , stringsAsFactors = F)

library(tidyverse)
# melt the dataframe(reshape from wide to long format):
v_melt <- reshape2::melt(v, id.vars = "id")

# modify the aggregation variables
v_melt <- v_melt %>%
  mutate(var = substr(as.character(variable), 3, 8),
     group_id = paste0(substr(as.character(variable), 1, 2), "_", id))

# reshape the data frame in a wide format:
v_cast <- reshape2::dcast(v_melt, group_id ~ var, value.var = "value")
```